# How to build MySQL plugin for Qt android?

Tags: android, mysql, qt

I’ve **qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.2.1** installed and I’m using **windows 8 64bit**.

I've Known that only sqlLite driver is available for android, but I want to use MySQL. So is there a tutorial more detailed than this [one](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Qt5_mysql_plugin_for_Android) 
explains how to build the MySQL driver for **Android on windows**.

**Note**: The Application I've built runs successfully on windows but it doesn't even open in android.

Comment: What is wrong about that tutorial? Have you tried to port [this](http://pastebin.com/k1u6gNe2) to Windows? In any case, you could grab the idea from there?

Comment: @LaszloPapp
First- in setting up the environment:
At the BR = I have Android-9, Android-14 and Android-18. is it okay to use the latest or I've to use 9.
Second- In the prerequisite should I download the MySQL connector for C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

I handled same project request the Android Apps work with MYSQL.
But our solution is using RSS and external XML to read/write the database.
Sorry about that cannot really help with your problem.
If RSS and PHP page is acceptable. I think you can try with it.